# apachectl command doesn't work from SSH

Tags: apache, ssh, webserver, redhat, httpd.conf

We have one redhat linux enterprise 7.0 server.

I installed Apache 2.4.6 (last version) on this server.

Once i check the version of apache with **apachectl -v** command on the server terminal, i am getting below result and it is ok.

[image]

But when i tried same command from a different machine by using SSH Secure Shell, i am getting no result from this **(apachectl -v)** command as shown below.
[image]

What is the problem here? Is there any SSH setting regarding this command? We need to run apachectl -v command from SSH-Outside.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: not sure...but you don't seem to be on the same server (up->gtxprod, down->gtxtest)....

Comment: thanks for warning @AndreGelinas. I fixed the screenshoot now.

Comment: then..I can't see why with those information. I'm always reaching my servers by SSH (don't have physical access anyway) and I'm able to do that on all of them. What's bothering me most actually is that you don't seem to have an error, just nothing....do any other command ( like ls or anything) give a result ?

Comment: for example for httpd command everything is ok for both on server or SSH

Comment: stupid question...is that the right apachectl ? did you do a "which apachectl" to make sure you were using the right one in the PATH ?...I can't see anything else..sorry :(